# Morphism $X\to\mathsf{R}_{T/S}(X)$ to a Weil restriction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:T\to S$ be a morphism of base schemes and $q_X:X\to T$ a $T$-scheme. Assume the Weil restriction $R_{T/S}(X)$ exists, i.e. there is an $S$-scheme $R_{T/S}X\to S$ such that
$$ \hom_T(U\times_S T,X) \simeq \hom_S(U,R_{T/S}(X)), $$
natural in $U$.

> Is there always a map $u$ which fits in to the following diagram?
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
> X @>{u (?)}>> R_{T/S}(X)\\
> @V{q_X}VV @VVV \\
> T @>{f}>> S
> \end{CD}
>   Where does it come from?

Notes:

- This question is somehow dual to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904030/weil-restriction-for-schemes).
- For a long time, I thought that I could just start from the pullback diagram
  \begin{CD}
  X\times_S T @>{p_1}>> X\\
  @V{p_2}VV @V{q_X}VV \\
  T @>{f}>> S
  \end{CD}
  and apply the defining property (i.e. the adjunction between base change and Weil restriction) to $p_1\in\hom(X\times_S T,X)\simeq \hom(X,R_{T/S}X)$. But it seems this doesn't work because the little subscript requires you to have a morphism of $T$-schemes to begin with and $p_1$ is not $T$-linear, in fact $X$ is not even a $T$-scheme.
- The question may be more category-theoretical in flavor then scheme-theoretic, in fact you can ask the same question about an arbitrary category a pullback functor $f^*:\mathcal C_{/S}\to\mathcal C_{/T}$ and a (perhaps partial) right adjoint $f^*\dashv f_*$. There is always a $\mathcal C$-arrow $f^*X\to X$, but is there also a $\mathcal C$-arrow $X\to f_*X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compose $q_X$ with $f$, this makes $X$ an $S$-scheme. Taking $U$ to be $X$ with this $S$-scheme structure we have one of two canonical projections $p_1 \in \hom_T(X\times_S T,X)$, from the commutative diagram of this fibered product it is easy to see that this projection is indeed $T$-linear. Map $u \in \hom_S(X,R_{T/S}(X))$ is the map corresponding to this projection under given bijection, and your commutative diagram for $u$ just means that $u$ an $S$-linear map, where $X/S$ is as above.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I literally cannot believe that have overlooked this for so long, so I will check back a few times in the coming days to see if I'm still convinced :-)

Comment: You say it is easy to see that this map is T-linear, but I am not so convinced. For instance taking $X=T$ or more precisely $\mathrm{id}:T\to T$, we get the map $p_1\in \hom(T\times_S T,T)$ where $T\times_ST$ is a $T$-scheme through the map $p_2$. To say that this is $T$-linear says that $p_1=p_2$...?

Comment: In other words, I can see how applying the adjunction $f_!\dashv f^*$ to $\mathrm{id}:f^*f_!X\to f^*f_!X$ gives you a map $f_!f^*f_!X\to f_!X$ I am not convinced that this arrow is itself of the form $f_!$(something) which would imply an arrow $f^*f_!X\to X$ as you say.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, because I am mildly convinced it is the best that can be said about it...